example.com. CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org" equivalent in windows server DNS
I want to create equivalent of: example.com. CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org" in my internal windows DNS server, Using powershell or any other way, how to do this?

CAA records are not directly supported with Windows DNS Server (2016+) within the GUI or PS. But it should be possible to add CAAs using the "unknown record" type 257.
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -name <NAME> -RecordData <HEXADECIMAL CONTENT> -Type 257 -ZoneName EXAMPLE.COM

While I have not tested this, it should also be possible to add CAA records to the zonefile itself in %windir%\System32\dns and reload the zone. This would work only on local zone files, though.

should  be letsencrypt.org?

<NAME> is the name of your record. If you use example.com as your ZoneName, a name of "letsencrypt.org" would result in a hostname of letsencrypt.org.example.com. While this is technically possible, you most certainly want to use your hostname or none if empty.
